# Max and minimum height on the surface

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Determine the points of maximum and minimum height with relation with the $z$-axis of the surface $\Sigma=\{(u,v,w)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}; (u-2)^{2}+2(v+1)^{2}+(w-1)^{2}=1\}$.  I know that the solution method relies on Lagrange multipliers, but my difficulty is finding the restriction.

Comment: Should $(z-1)^2$ be $(w-1)^2?$

Comment: What is the function you are trying to maximize?  I know it's the height, what's the formula?  Once you have this, I think you'll see what the restriction is.

Comment: maybe it should be z=w?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can apply Lagrange multipliers to

- $f(u,v,w)=w$

with constraint

- $(u-2)^{2}+2(v+1)^{2}+(w-1)^{2}=1$